# Specify custom "folder" name for filename display of virtual documents in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When you open two files in VSCode that have the same filename, VSCode will helpfully display the folder name alongside the filename so that you can tell the two files apart:

[image: same file name]

In my VSCode extension, I make extensive use of [virtual documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-documents) to display text-based content. However, I can't quite seem to replicate this behaviour of showing the folder name as additional context in the tab.

For example, I have the following two virtual documents:

- The "virtual" path of the first one is `sql/FJ5G91KN/queries.sql`
- and the "virtual" path of the second one is `sql/6D3B7G5K/queries.sql`

[image: virtual documents]

However, VSCode does not display those "virtual" folder names (FJ5G91KN and 6D3B7G5K) as additional context in the tab.

How can I get VSCode to show the "virtual" folder name just as it automatically does when you have two regular files opened that have the same filename?

Thanks!

Comment: create an issue at the VSC repo

Comment: Their issue template requests you ask questions on SO or open a discussion on GitHub, which I have now also done: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/640

Comment: if the API does not give you the possibility to add these descriptive fields, a questions on SO would not give you any more information, and if the API can do it it is a documentation issue

Comment: In my experience, the APIs are not very straightforward around this and yeah some things are not documented. But I have a sense this is possible and I'm hoping someone knows, hence the question here and on GitHub to get more eyes on it!

Comment: if you use the virt doc sample extension, do you get the same behavior? If so it is a bug, because tabs use URI's and show the folders for duplicate file names